# How can I parse different tags data and store them separately?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse class: `fixture_date` and class: `play_team` separately from the following website.

http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/series/1128817.html?template=fixtures.

Code:

```
import re
import pytz
import requests
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from espncricinfo.exceptions import MatchNotFoundError, NoScorecardError
from espncricinfo.match import Match

bigbash_article_link = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/series/1128817.html?template=fixtures"

    r = requests.get(bigbash_article_link)
    bigbash_article_html = r.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(bigbash_article_html, "html.parser")


    bigbash1_items = soup.find_all("span",{"class": "fixture_date"})
    #print(bigbash1_items)
    bigbash_items = soup.find_all("span",{"class": "play_team"})
    date = {}
    team = {}

    for div in bigbash_items:
         team = [div.find('a').string.strip("\n\r")]
         print(team)
    for div in bigbash1_items:
         date = [div.string.strip("\xa0local\n\r\t")]
         print(date)
```

output:

```
['1st Match - Peshawar Zalmi v Multan Sultans']
['2nd Match - Karachi Kings v Quetta Gladiators']
['3rd Match - Multan Sultans v Lahore Qalandars']
['4th Match - Islamabad United v Peshawar Zalmi']
['5th Match - Quetta Gladiators v Lahore Qalandars']
['6th Match - Multan Sultans v Islamabad United']
['7th Match - Karachi Kings v Peshawar Zalmi']
['8th Match - Karachi Kings v Lahore Qalandars']
['9th Match - Islamabad United v Quetta Gladiators']
['10th Match - Quetta Gladiators v Peshawar Zalmi']
['11th Match - Multan Sultans v Karachi Kings']
['12th Match - Lahore Qalandars v Islamabad United']
['13th Match - Multan Sultans v Quetta Gladiators']
['14th Match - Peshawar Zalmi v Lahore Qalandars']
['15th Match - Islamabad United v Karachi Kings']
['16th Match - Peshawar Zalmi v Multan Sultans']
['17th Match - Multan Sultans v Quetta Gladiators']
['18th Match - Islamabad United v Lahore Qalandars']
['19th Match - Karachi Kings v Quetta Gladiators']
['20th Match - Multan Sultans v Lahore Qalandars']
['21st Match - Peshawar Zalmi v Islamabad United']
['22nd Match - Multan Sultans v Karachi Kings']
['23rd Match - Peshawar Zalmi v Quetta Gladiators']
['24th Match - Karachi Kings v Lahore Qalandars']
['25th Match - Multan Sultans v Islamabad United']
['26th Match - Quetta Gladiators v Lahore Qalandars']
['27th Match - Peshawar Zalmi v Karachi Kings']
['28th Match - Quetta Gladiators v Islamabad United']
['29th Match - Peshawar Zalmi v Lahore Qalandars']
['30th Match - Islamabad United v Karachi Kings']
['Qualifier - TBC v TBC']
['Eliminator 1 - TBC v TBC']
['Eliminator 2 - TBC v TBC']
['Final - TBC v TBC']
['Thu Feb 22']
['21:00']
['Fri Feb 23']
['15:30']
['Fri Feb 23']
['20:00']
['Sat Feb 24']
['15:30']
['Sat Feb 24']
['20:00']
['Sun Feb 25']
['15:30']
['Sun Feb 25']
['20:00']
['Mon Feb 26']
['20:00']
['Wed Feb 28']
['20:00']
['Thu Mar 1']
['20:00']
['Fri Mar 2']
['15:30']
['Fri Mar 2']
['20:00']
['Sat Mar 3']
['15:30']
['Sat Mar 3']
['20:00']
['Sun Mar 4']
['20:00']
['Tue Mar 6']
['20:00']
['Wed Mar 7']
['20:00']
['Thu Mar 8']
['15:30']
['Thu Mar 8']
['20:00']
['Fri Mar 9']
['15:30']
['Fri Mar 9']
['20:00']
['Sat Mar 10']
['15:30']
['Sat Mar 10']
['20:00']
['Sun Mar 11']
['20:00']
['Tue Mar 13']
['20:00']
['Wed Mar 14']
['20:00']
['Thu Mar 15']
['15:30']
['Thu Mar 15']
['20:00']
['Fri Mar 16']
['15:30']
['Fri Mar 16']
['20:00']
['Sun Mar 18']
['20:00']
['Tue Mar 20']
['Wed Mar 21']
['Sun Mar 25']
```

I want to store these values in list of dictionary like

expected output:

```
[{'team':'1st Match - Peshawar Zalmi v Multan Sultans','date':'Thu Feb 22', 'time':'21:00'}
{'team':'2nd Match - Karachi Kings v Quetta Gladiators','date':'Thu Feb 23', 'time':'15:30'}
{'team':'3rd Match - Multan Sultans v Lahore Qalandars','date':'Thu Feb 24', 'time':'20:00'}
.....{'team':'Eliminator 1 - TBC v TBC','date':'Wed Mar 21', 'time':''}{'team':'Final - TBC v TBC','date':'Sun Mar 25', 'time':''}]
```

problem is date = {} contains both date and time values separate list, how can I do this?

Comment: Have you thought about using that `Download Fixtures` button at the top? The output `.ics` file seems like it might be easy to parse too.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce thanks for commenting, I want to render these value to a template, if I use .ics file contents then I have to enter manually to HTML file also they may change the schedule, So dynamically rendering will be a better option.

Comment: Wouldn't that file be updated too if they changed the schedule though? I wrote a quick script that parses the `.ics` file and gives all the information you seem to be looking for.

Comment: Please share that script I will look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code parses the downloaded "fixtures" file that you can download at the top of the url you gave. I know it's not the way to seem to prefer but the information seems fairly up to date. For example, the website shows matches that seem to have been played already (from February) but the `.ics` file starts with a match that is to be played tomorrow (March 2nd).

```
>>> import re
... from datetime import datetime
... 
... REGEX = re.compile(r'''\
... SUMMARY:(?P<team>.+)\n
... DTSTART:(?P<start>.+)\n
... DTEND:(?P<end>.+)\n
... LOCATION:(?P<location>.+)\n''', re.VERBOSE)
... 
... 
... def to_datetime(s):
...     return datetime.strptime(s, '%Y%m%dT%H%M00Z')
... 
... 
... result = []
... with open('Pakistan_Super_League.ics', 'r') as f:
...     for m in REGEX.finditer(f.read()):
...         current = m.groupdict()
...         start = to_datetime(current['start'])
...         result.append({
...             'team': current['team'],
...             'date': start.strftime('%a %b %d'),
...             'time': start.strftime('%H:%M')
...         })
... 
>>> for event in result:
...     print(event)
... 
{'team': '11th Match Multan Sultans v Karachi Kings', 'date': 'Fri Mar 02', 'time': '11:30'}
{'team': '12th Match Lahore Qalandars v Islamabad United', 'date': 'Fri Mar 02', 'time': '16:00'}
{'team': '13th Match Multan Sultans v Quetta Gladiators', 'date': 'Sat Mar 03', 'time': '11:30'}
{'team': '14th Match Peshawar Zalmi v Lahore Qalandars', 'date': 'Sat Mar 03', 'time': '16:00'}
{'team': '15th Match Islamabad United v Karachi Kings', 'date': 'Sun Mar 04', 'time': '16:00'}
{'team': '16th Match Peshawar Zalmi v Multan Sultans', 'date': 'Tue Mar 06', 'time': '16:00'}
{'team': '17th Match Multan Sultans v Quetta Gladiators', 'date': 'Wed Mar 07', 'time': '16:00'}
{'team': '18th Match Islamabad United v Lahore Qalandars', 'date': 'Thu Mar 08', 'time': '11:30'}
{'team': '19th Match Karachi Kings v Quetta Gladiators', 'date': 'Thu Mar 08', 'time': '16:00'}
{'team': '20th Match Multan Sultans v Lahore Qalandars', 'date': 'Fri Mar 09', 'time': '11:30'}
{'team': '21st Match Peshawar Zalmi v Islamabad United', 'date': 'Fri Mar 09', 'time': '16:00'}
{'team': '22nd Match Multan Sultans v Karachi Kings', 'date': 'Sat Mar 10', 'time': '11:30'}
{'team': '23rd Match Peshawar Zalmi v Quetta Gladiators', 'date': 'Sat Mar 10', 'time': '16:00'}
{'team': '24th Match Karachi Kings v Lahore Qalandars', 'date': 'Sun Mar 11', 'time': '16:00'}
{'team': '25th Match Multan Sultans v Islamabad United', 'date': 'Tue Mar 13', 'time': '16:00'}
{'team': '26th Match Quetta Gladiators v Lahore Qalandars', 'date': 'Wed Mar 14', 'time': '16:00'}
{'team': '27th Match Peshawar Zalmi v Karachi Kings', 'date': 'Thu Mar 15', 'time': '11:30'}
{'team': '28th Match Quetta Gladiators v Islamabad United', 'date': 'Thu Mar 15', 'time': '16:00'}
{'team': '29th Match Peshawar Zalmi v Lahore Qalandars', 'date': 'Fri Mar 16', 'time': '11:30'}
{'team': '30th Match Islamabad United v Karachi Kings', 'date': 'Fri Mar 16', 'time': '16:00'}
{'team': 'Qualifier TBD v TBD', 'date': 'Sun Mar 18', 'time': '16:00'}
{'team': 'Eliminator 1 TBD v TBD', 'date': 'Tue Mar 20', 'time': '00:00'}
{'team': 'Eliminator 2 TBD v TBD', 'date': 'Wed Mar 21', 'time': '00:00'}
{'team': 'Final TBD v TBD', 'date': 'Sun Mar 25', 'time': '00:00'}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is more simple to do just by using .ics file but it is difficult to render key values of start and end since it contains DateTime.DateTime, can I format it and arrange such that I get only date and time

Comment: suppose {% for i in event %}
{{ i['date'] }}
{{ i['time'] }}
{{ i['team'] }}
{% endfor %}, I should be able to print like this    Fri Mar 2
15:30 
11th Match - Multan Sultans v Karachi Kings

Comment: Perfect, Thanks. can you explain me how it is done using datetime module?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a quick look at the inspected element, each row (each fixture) is present inside the following tag:

```
<li class="large-20 medium-20 columns" team1="xxxx" team2="xxxx" venue="xxxx">
```

So, you can iterate over that and get the team, date and time in each loop.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/series/1128817.html?template=fixtures')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

fixtures = []

for row in soup.find_all('li', class_='large-20 medium-20 columns'):
    team = row.find('span', class_='play_team').a.text.strip('\n\r')
    date_and_time = row.find_all('span', class_='fixture_date')
    date = date_and_time[0].text.strip()
    try:
        time = date_and_time[1].text.strip('\xa0local\n\r\t')
    except IndexError:
        time = ''

    fixtures.append({'team': team, 'date': date, 'time': time})

for f in fixtures:
    print(f)
```

Output:

```
{'team': '1st Match - Peshawar Zalmi v Multan Sultans', 'date': 'Thu Feb 22', 'time': '21:00'}
{'team': '2nd Match - Karachi Kings v Quetta Gladiators', 'date': 'Fri Feb 23', 'time': '15:30'}
{'team': '3rd Match - Multan Sultans v Lahore Qalandars', 'date': 'Fri Feb 23', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '4th Match - Islamabad United v Peshawar Zalmi', 'date': 'Sat Feb 24', 'time': '15:30'}
{'team': '5th Match - Quetta Gladiators v Lahore Qalandars', 'date': 'Sat Feb 24', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '6th Match - Multan Sultans v Islamabad United', 'date': 'Sun Feb 25', 'time': '15:30'}
{'team': '7th Match - Karachi Kings v Peshawar Zalmi', 'date': 'Sun Feb 25', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '8th Match - Karachi Kings v Lahore Qalandars', 'date': 'Mon Feb 26', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '9th Match - Islamabad United v Quetta Gladiators', 'date': 'Wed Feb 28', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '10th Match - Quetta Gladiators v Peshawar Zalmi', 'date': 'Thu Mar 1', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '11th Match - Multan Sultans v Karachi Kings', 'date': 'Fri Mar 2', 'time': '15:30'}
{'team': '12th Match - Lahore Qalandars v Islamabad United', 'date': 'Fri Mar 2', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '13th Match - Multan Sultans v Quetta Gladiators', 'date': 'Sat Mar 3', 'time': '15:30'}
{'team': '14th Match - Peshawar Zalmi v Lahore Qalandars', 'date': 'Sat Mar 3', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '15th Match - Islamabad United v Karachi Kings', 'date': 'Sun Mar 4', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '16th Match - Peshawar Zalmi v Multan Sultans', 'date': 'Tue Mar 6', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '17th Match - Multan Sultans v Quetta Gladiators', 'date': 'Wed Mar 7', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '18th Match - Islamabad United v Lahore Qalandars', 'date': 'Thu Mar 8', 'time': '15:30'}
{'team': '19th Match - Karachi Kings v Quetta Gladiators', 'date': 'Thu Mar 8', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '20th Match - Multan Sultans v Lahore Qalandars', 'date': 'Fri Mar 9', 'time': '15:30'}
{'team': '21st Match - Peshawar Zalmi v Islamabad United', 'date': 'Fri Mar 9', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '22nd Match - Multan Sultans v Karachi Kings', 'date': 'Sat Mar 10', 'time': '15:30'}
{'team': '23rd Match - Peshawar Zalmi v Quetta Gladiators', 'date': 'Sat Mar 10', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '24th Match - Karachi Kings v Lahore Qalandars', 'date': 'Sun Mar 11', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '25th Match - Multan Sultans v Islamabad United', 'date': 'Tue Mar 13', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '26th Match - Quetta Gladiators v Lahore Qalandars', 'date': 'Wed Mar 14', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '27th Match - Peshawar Zalmi v Karachi Kings', 'date': 'Thu Mar 15', 'time': '15:30'}
{'team': '28th Match - Quetta Gladiators v Islamabad United', 'date': 'Thu Mar 15', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': '29th Match - Peshawar Zalmi v Lahore Qalandars', 'date': 'Fri Mar 16', 'time': '15:30'}
{'team': '30th Match - Islamabad United v Karachi Kings', 'date': 'Fri Mar 16', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': 'Qualifier - TBC v TBC', 'date': 'Sun Mar 18', 'time': '20:00'}
{'team': 'Eliminator 1 - TBC v TBC', 'date': 'Tue Mar 20', 'time': ''}
{'team': 'Eliminator 2 - TBC v TBC', 'date': 'Wed Mar 21', 'time': ''}
{'team': 'Final - TBC v TBC', 'date': 'Sun Mar 25', 'time': ''}
```